# How to use a dict for resampling a multindex pandas data frame? (>0.18.0)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pivot-table

Before pandas 0.18.0 I used to be able to do resample my deeply pivoted table like so:

```
pivot_df = SoilSensorDf.pivot(status_df, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
resample_methods = map({'A': 'sum',
                        'B': 'mean',
                        'C': 'min'}.get,
                    [x[0] for x in pivot_df.columns])
resample_method_tuple_list = zip(pivot_df.columns, resample_methods)
resample_dict = dict(resample_method_tuple_list)
pivot_df.resample('D', how=resample_dict)
```

But with pandas 0.18.1, the docs suggest I do it this way

```
pivot_df.resample('D').agg(resample_dict)
```

But this gives me the following error which I can't seem to figure out how to resolve. Anyone have any ideas?

```
File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 293, in aggregate
result, how = self._aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)


File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 545, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 496, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 475, in _agg_1dim
    colg = self._gotitem(name, ndim=1, subset=subset)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 352, in _gotitem
    return grouped[key]
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 330, in __getitem__
    if len(self.obj.columns.intersection(key)) != len(key):
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 2031, in intersection
    other, result_names = self._convert_can_do_setop(other)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 2095, in _convert_can_do_setop
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: other must be a MultiIndex or a list of tuples
```

Example to demonstrate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'),
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='1400T', periods=10))
df['D'] = ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y']
df.index.name = "timestamp"
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(), values=['A', 'B'], index="timestamp",
                          columns=['C', 'D'])
resample_methods = map({'A': 'sum', 'B': 'mean'}.get, [x[0] for x in df_pivot.columns])
resample_method_tuple_list = zip(df_pivot.columns, resample_methods)
resample_dict = dict(resample_method_tuple_list)
df_pivot.resample('D').agg(resample_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug that will be worked on by the pandas team:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13914